# How to replace characters in a string in python

Tags: python

How to replace characters in a string which we know the exact indexes in python?

Ex : name = "ABCDEFGH"
        I need to change all odd index positions characters into '$' character.

```
    name = "A$C$E$G$"
```

(Considered indexes bigin from 0 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name = "ABCDEFGH"
nameL = list(name)

for i in range(len(nameL)):
    if i%2==1:
        nameL[i] = '$'

name = ''.join(nameL)
print(name)
```

Answer (score 12):

Also `'$'.join(s[::2])`
Just takes even letters, casts them to a list of chars and then interleaves $

```
 ''.join(['$' if i in idx else s[i] for i in range(len(s))])
```

works for any index array idx

Comment: You don't even need the `list()` call. :)

Comment: Question is based on the indices so this is not a proper way!

Comment: In general for this sort of manipulation, convert to a list, manipulate the indices in the list then join back to a string, but in this specific example as you showed it collapses down beautifully into a join and slice with skip.

Comment: @Kasramvd, it's an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yeah a sort of! but not completely!

Comment: @Kasramvd Added a general soln as well. Pythonic but not as elegant.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `enumerate` to loop over the string and get the indices in each iteration then based your logic you can keep the proper elements :

```
>>> ''.join([j if i%2==0 else '$' for i,j in enumerate(name)])
'A$C$E$G$'
```

Comment: You could shorten this slightly with `'$' if i%2 else j`.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference string elements by index and form a new string.  Something like this should work:

```
startingstring = 'mylittlestring'
nstr = ''
for i in range(0,len(startingstring)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
            nstr += startingstring[i]
    else:
            nstr += '$'
```

Then do with `nstr` as you like.

Comment: The reason why the other solutions use a list with `join` is to avoid this - you are creating a new string object each time you use `+=`.

Comment: I did not know that.  I figured it was, in effect, appended to an existing string.  What's the detail of the operation?  Does it (1) create a new string consisting of the old `nstr` concatenated with the new character, (2) delete the old `nstr` and (3) move the new string to `nstr`?

Comment: You can't append to an existing string because strings are immutable in Python.

Comment: Just about, yes.  Python is not the only language like this, PHP and Java are examples that are the same.  Perl is the odd one out (in so many ways).

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for the post.

Comment: The discussion is worthwhile, although often repeated here.  It would be good to keep.